# Is it possible to send to the user a file in IBM Watson Assistant?

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson

I have a question, if I have an API that transforms my user input into a desired excel sheet or pdf file, is there a way in IBM Watson Assistant to display this file back to the user in the chat after finishing the call of the API? for example if I have an intent where the user can ask to transform some data to the excel or pdf file how can I send this result back to the user as a file?

Comment: share a link to the file. you will need to host it outside of WA